# How to get the changed (new) state value in React JS function with / without useEffect hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, react-functional-component

I just want to dynamically update the font sizes for source and target within a specific range (Here the range should be between 12 - 18). It is working but the updated/changed value is not reflecting on the next time function call. I know that we can use useEffect hook to make it reflect for some cases but in this scenario, I'm not sure whether the useEffect hook will be helpful or not

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React JS</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-datetime/3.0.0/react-datetime.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-datetime/3.0.0/css/react-datetime.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.2.0/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
        const { useState } = React
        const Editor = (props) => {
            const [sourceLanguageFontSize, setSourceLanguageFontSize] = useState(15)
                const [targetLanguageFontSize, setTargetLanguageFontSize] = useState(15)
            const [allowedMinFontSize, allowedMaxFontSize] = [12, 18]
            const changeFontSize = (stateVal, setFunction, action = '+') => {
                console.log(parseInt(stateVal)) //Here it prints old value
                if (parseInt(stateVal) >= allowedMinFontSize && parseInt(stateVal) <= allowedMaxFontSize) {
                    let currentFontSize = parseInt(stateVal)
                    if (action == '+')
                        setFunction(prevState => prevState + 1)
                    else if (action == '-')
                        setFunction(prevState => prevState - 1)
                }   
            }
            return(
                <span onClick={e => changeFontSize(sourceLanguageFontSize, setSourceLanguageFontSize, '+') }>Increase Source</span>
            )
        }
        ReactDOM.render(<Editor />,document.getElementById("root"))
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obviously it will log out the *current* (or *old*) state value, as that's the value you pass in *on click*: `changeFontSize(sourceLanguageFontSize, ...)`. Given that, your code is overly complex for such a simple task? Have you considered simply defining two callbacks to increase and decrease the value? For example: `const decrease = () => setSourceLanguageFontSize(current => current > allowedMinFontSize ? current - 1 : current);`

Comment: I just made it simple. Actually it has the target value which also is to be updated. so that I've used three arguments in that function

Comment: I don't follow, sorry?!

Answer (score 0):

Should work like this

```js
function editor (props) {
        const [count, setCount] = useState(15)
        const [sourceLanguageFontSize, setSourceLanguageFontSize] = useState(15)
            const [targetLanguageFontSize, setTargetLanguageFontSize] = useState(15)
        const [allowedMinFontSize, allowedMaxFontSize] = [12, 18]
        
        const changeFontSize = (action = '+') => {
            console.log(parseInt(sourceLanguageFontSize)) //Here it prints old value
            if (parseInt(sourceLanguageFontSize) >= allowedMinFontSize && parseInt(sourceLanguageFontSize) <= allowedMaxFontSize) {
                let currentFontSize = parseInt(sourceLanguageFontSize)
                if (action == '+')
                    setSourceLanguageFontSize(prevState => prevState + 1)
                else if (action == '-')
                    setSourceLanguageFontSize(prevState => prevState - 1)
            }   
        }
        return(
            
            <span onClick={e => changeFontSize('+') }>Increase Source</span>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Can you change the answer code based on the updated question code?

Comment: Actually I need to update the target font size as well that's why I pass three arguments. Just keep that as it is and update the answer

Comment: Then I don't understand what you want to achieve. You want to update `targetLanguageFontSize ` as well?